# RDC (mstsc.exe) remote access batch enable on clients?

Tags: mstsc

Is there a way to enable connections via RDC on multiple computers running WinXP Pro SP3?

Answer (score 2):

Are these computers in a domain where you can apply a group policy to them?

To enable remote connections with a group policy you'll need to enable this policy.

```
Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components/Terminal Services/Terminal Server/Connections\Allow users to connect remotely using Terminal Services
```

If your systems have the windows firewall enabled you will need to setup an exception for port 3389 in the windows Firewall.

```
Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Network/Network Connections/Windows Firewall/Domain Profile\Windows Firewall: Define inbound port exceptions.
```

You'll need a value of **3389:TCP:*:enabled:RDP**

To login a user will need to be in the group **Remote Desktop Users** or the local **Administrators** group.

Comment: It worked perfectly. 
Thanks for your help!